# What do you call a fire panel with tools?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

In Russia we have these "fire panels":

[image]

So, they have tools like a bucket and a spade, so you can dig up some sand with the spade in the summer and extinguish the fire with it. Or in winter you can use the bucket to scoop up some snow and extinguish the fire with snow...

Word for word translation for this type of fire panel would be "fire shield".

What is it called in English? Or do you not use these over there?

Comment: I've never seen one. I would call it something like "emergency equipment box" or "fire equipment locker", or some permtation of these.

Comment: You can call it a [_fire cabinet_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fire_cabinet). In modern buildings, it usually contains a fire hose and/or a fire extinguisher.

Comment: It's a very recognizable kind of thing (it's red, the contents are obviously for helping put out a fire), and at least in the US, there are similar boxes installed in buildings. Except the contents are entirely different. In the US, there might be an axe, or a fir extinguisher, or a length of hose attached to a water pipe. Those other items I've never seen in such a box in the US.

Comment: As to what the axe is for during the fire, it is presumably for amputating a hand that's in hand cuffs cuffed to a pipe while the ship is sinking, or I suppose you could smash the hand cuffs but that seems unlikely. Or for chopping down doors. Firemen always seem to want to do that instead of using the door handle.

Comment: @Mitch, what you see in the picture is not a standard collection of things in these fire boxes, other ones might also include an axe and the other things. So, since you guys have it, do you know for name for it that you use in the US? (I am learning American English)

Comment: 'fire box', in American English, is the pole and [red box at the end of the street that used to be used for notifying the fire department that your house is on fire](https://www.google.com/search?q=fire+box) (911 on your phone is what is used now, but the boxes are still maintained, at least in New England). The red box that holds an axe or an extinguisher or a hose, I'm not sure I would call it anything in particular. [An image search for 'red box with axe'](https://www.google.com/search?q=red+box+with+axe) uses words like 'cabinet'. I would just say "Get the axe!" and you'd know where to go.

Comment: You can call it **Red fire stand.**